# Windows Server 2016 WDS BINLSVC error

Tags: windows-server-2016, deployment, wds

I try to setup a new WDS server, but in the eventlog i get this fault when i try to boot from network:

```
    An error occurred while trying to create the directory for the  architecture. 
    Error Information: 0x3

- System 

  - Provider 

   [ Name]  BINLSVC 

  - EventID 1284 

   [ Qualifiers]  49413 

   Level 2 

   Task 5 

   Keywords 0x80000000000000 

  - TimeCreated 

   [ SystemTime]  2019-07-16T14:24:34.700279400Z 

   EventRecordID 3236 

   Channel Application 

   Computer LECSOSRV2016 

   Security 


- EventData 


   0x3
```

The server is Win2016 standard server on physical machine (it is worked for me a half year ago). When my router is broked, then i reinstall the server and set-up a Hyper-V guest with pFsense. The WDS is standalone, Variable Window Extension is turned off. DHCP, DNS is provided by the server, each checkbox is checked on the DHCP page.

What i've try until this moment:

1. Reinstall the whole server.
2. Check the permission of the D:\RemoteInstall folder (WDSServer have a full access), and on the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WDSServer (SYSTEM have a full access).
3. I ran the `wdsutil /Uninitialize-Server` and `wdsutil /Initialize-Server` command from Admin prompt, and recheck the WDS properties.
4. Changed the boot image to a Windows 10 1607 boot.wim for x64 and x86 architecture.

I can't find any appropriate solution because everywhere recommend to use the "wdsutil", but it's not work for me.

Comment: Can you set everyone as full control to see if that fixes the issue?

Comment: I set it on the RemoteFolder and in the registry on the WDSServer. This is eliminate the problem. But the Deployment is not working, the tftp client drop a timeout error.

Comment: After 1 WDS Service restart the problem came back :(

Comment: Hmmmm, does seem to be a permission error. Is it possible to reimage the wds server?

Comment: This is my own home server, so i can do anything with it without any problem.I will reinstall again the entire system, and we'll see, it is ok. But this installation was a fresh install too. Not older than two weeks.

Comment: So this is an error that it threw out of the box after WDS provisioning? There are no other apps or tweaks?

Comment: Two other app, qBittorrent and UniversalMediaPlayer running in the background. And one hyper-v guest (pFsense), which provide the internet connection via 2 separated (dual port ethernet) card.

Comment: Let's try to add the wds server to the machine before adding the other stuff to it. E.g. getting network boot to work then adding one feature at a time back to it.

Comment: Sunday I will try it out.